# stringstream issue

Tags: c++, stringstream

I cannot get the following stringstreamm to compile

```
stringstream qss;

qss.operator <<  "some text " ::stringstream.operator << DDateTime::date2Oracle(dFrom) ::stringstream.operator <<  " more text " ::stringstream.operator <<  DDateTime::date2Oracle(dUntil);
```

If I just use the `<<` operator without the `::stringstream.operator`it complains about the operator being ambigious, now it complains about incorrect syntax...

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'std::stringstream'
```

EDIT:

**error C2593: 'operator <<' is ambiguous
        c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\Vc7\include\ostream(434): could be 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::_Myt &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::_Mysb *)'
        with
        [
            _Elem=char,
            _Traits=std::char_traits
        ]**

Comment: We need the second line where alternative is described :)

Comment: We need to know the type that DDateTime returns.

Comment: string DDateTime::date2Oracle(DATE Date)

Comment: Yeah, I bet it is something that have conversion to `std::string` and to something else as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is obvious that whatever type `DDateTime::date2Oracle(dFrom)` returns does not implement `<<` operator. So you will have to write one yourself.

As for the syntax, first of all you have to call it just like a function which it actually is:

```
stringstream qss;
operator<<(
     (operator<<(qss <<  "some text ", 
                 DDateTime::date2Oracle(dFrom)) << " more text "),
      DDateTime::date2Oracle(dUntil));
```

And second of all, `stringstream` defined in `std` namespace, so you have to write it like `std::stringstream` or `::std::stringstream`. `::stringstream` will look for it in global namespace and there is no such class defined there.

BTW, `operator<<` usually is implemented as free function, so `qss.operator<<` wouldn't work.

Comment: explanation+1, also try what agsamek suggested.

Comment: date2Oracle() returns a std::string

Comment: @Tony, then check error message again. `stringstream` does work with `std::string` out of the box and the issue is somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

The `operator` keywords don't belong here, leave them out:

```
qss << "some text" << DDateTime::date2Oracle(dFrom) << " more text " <<  DDateTime::date2Oracle(dUntil);
```

This should be perfectly valid and unambiguous, unless the `date2Oracle` function is ambiguously overloaded.

The correct pattern for implementing `operator<<` for a type `T` is:

```
template<typename Char, typename Traits>
std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>
operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>& stream, const T& object) {
  // now put something into the stream
  return stream;   // return stream << xyz ... is also possible
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the operator like a  function.

```
std::stringstream s;

operator<<(s, "Your string")
```

Comment: You might also need to define an appropriate operator overload for your type: `std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const DDateTime& d) {...}`

Answer (score 2):

Go really funky:

```
qss.operator <<("some text ");
qss.operator <<(DDateTime::date2Oracle(dFrom));
qss.operator <<(" more text "); 
qss.operator <<(DDateTime::date2Oracle(dUntil));
```

And you'll probably get a better idea where the ambiguity is.

Comment: will that produce the same effect as doing qss << "text" << Somefunc() << "more text";   ???

Comment: operator<< should return the stream so it can be used by the next operator<<.  This is called chaining and should be the same as the function-notation

Answer (score 1):

Cast to / construct string explicitly:

```
qss << "some text " << string(DDateTime::date2Oracle(dFrom)) 
    <<  " more text " <<  string(DDateTime::date2Oracle(dUntil));
```

Comment: No, this is the wrong way. There must exist an overload of `operator<<` that takes a type compatible with the return type of the `date2Oracle` function as second argument.

Comment: No - there need to be a conversion to string, which most probably exists. If you have downvoted my answer - please consider upvoting instead.

Comment: I haven't downvoted. But in C++ you do conversions to string *by implementing `operator<<`* and then applying a stringstream or `boost::lexical_cast`, not the other way round! Also, `string(...)` is an old-style cast which should be avoided in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be enough with `qss << "some text " << DDateTime...`?

Answer (score 0):

What's stopping you from doing:

```
stringstream s;
s << "some text" << (DDateTime::date2Oracle(dFrom)) << "more text" << (DDateTime::date2Oracle(dUntil)) ;
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's the correct syntax. If this doesn't work, the call to the `date2Oracle` function is ambiguous and the question is in fact unrelated to stringstreams or `operator<<`.

Comment: @Tony the important part is that I've enclosed the `DDateTime::date2Oracle` in parenthesis.  Now it can't be confused by the `::` operator.

Comment: But `::` and `()` have a much higher predecence than `<<`. This can't be the problem.